# @font-face doesn't work

Tags: css, font-face

I downloaded a font `inlove-light-wf.ttf`, in order to use the rule `@font-face`.

I have in my folder: `home.html` and `inlove-light-wf.ttf`.

In my CSS I have :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inlove';
    src: url('inlove-light-wf.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#definicao{
    text-align:center;
    color:#0080C0;
    font-family:'Inlove';
    font-size:24px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top:solid #999 thin;
    padding: 20px 40px 3px 40px;
    height:290px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
}

#definicao{
    text-align:center;
    color:#0080C0;
    font-family:'Inlove';
    font-size:24px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top:solid #999 thin;
    padding: 20px 40px 3px 40px;
    height:290px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the font-weight and font-style properties in your #definicao rule to 'normal'?

Comment: is the CSS defined in a different file from the HTML or inline inside `home.html` ?

Comment: Besides the usual is the css path correct to your ttf file, you need to make sure your server is actually setup to serve up ttf files.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One source of the problem could be if your css is in a separate file that isn't in the root folder.  For example, if you keep all of your css files in a 'css' folder, you'll need to modify the font url to be relative to that file, not to the root folder.  In this example it would be `src: url('../inlove-light-wf.ttf');`

Furthermore, not all browsers can use .ttf font files. You have to declare alternative font formats in the `@font-face` css.

Here's a modified `@font-face` declaration to get you started. I would also recommend reading more [here](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/fixing-ie9-font-face-problems) and [here](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/).

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inlove';
    src: url('inlove-light-wf.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('inlove-light-wf.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('inlove-light-wf.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('inlove-light-wf.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('inlove-light-wf.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@font-face` rule usually doesn't support some old browsers. I usually use [font-face](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) generator which will generate css file from your font that you need to include, and all browsers will show it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with font too. When font was working in IE wasn't on iPhone and when was working on iPhone wasn't in IE. Here is my code (i don't know why it works this way, but it does for me):

```css
@font-face{
 font-family:"Royal Chicken";
 src: url(../gradivo/font/RoyaChicken.eot);
        src: url(../gradivo/font/RoyalChicken.ttf)  format("truetype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
      url(../gradivo/font/RoyalChicken.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
             url(../gradivo/font/RoyalChicken.woff) format("woff"), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
             url(../gradivo/font/RoyalChicken.svg#RoyalChicken) format("svg");
}
@font-face{
 font-family:"Royal Chicken";
 src: url(../gradivo/font/RoyaChicken.eot);
}
@font-face{
 font-family:"Royal Chicken";
        src: url(../gradivo/font/RoyalChicken.ttf)  format("truetype");
}
```

It may help you. :)