# Having trouble with using @font-face

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I can't seem to get @font-face to work for my site. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Does this look right?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'bebas_neue_regularregular';
src: url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.svg#bebas_neue_regularregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}

@font-face {
font-family: 'vollkornregular';
src: url('../fonts/vollkorn-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/vollkorn-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/vollkorn-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../fonts/vollkorn-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/vollkorn-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/vollkorn-regular-webfont.svg#vollkornregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589758/font-face-doesnt-work

Comment: Did you get any console error?

Comment: No , but it works fine in ie just not in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

The `@font-face` rule usually doesn't support some old browsers. I usually use [font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) which will generate css file from your font that you need to include, and all browsers will show it correctly.

Comment: That's what I used. It gave me that code. All I did was direct it to the folder where my fonts are. Its only working for ie.